# Desktop items disappear from screen and finder solely due to second monitor

Tags: display, desktop

I have a second monitor. When I connect the monitor to my Mac Pro by HDMI the desktop items automatically disappear. The strange thing is that they don't just disappear from the actual desktop but they aren't in Finder or anywhere on the computer. As soon as I unplug the second monitor they return immediately. So there isn't a concern about using desktop items, this just makes my second monitor a big paperweight.

Comment: If your second monitor is set to be primary then they could go there.

Comment: No. The desktop items don’t show up on either monitor. Plus they entirely dissapear in Finder. If I search for them they aren’t there. As soon as I unplug the monitor they instantly appear.

Comment: sounds like they go outside the visible area.  Does moving the physical layout in "Display" settings alter anything?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the visible area. As I explained, the desktop files completely disappear from Finder and I can’t search for them. In essence, the OS thinks the files and folders are not even on the hard drive.